# my map app stops unexpectedly

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm new to android.
I'm working on a app using google map. But after several test, I have the same problem : the app stops unexpectedly.

I present the code.

The Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.map_project"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.map_project.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.map_project.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MyKeyxxx" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

the map_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the MainActivity:

```
 package com.map_project;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

        GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    }


}
```

when I run the application on my phone, I get the message: Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped.
If anyone can help me, it would be nice because I begin to despair.

Comment: Initially your map will be null.

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly i would like to know are you testing it on Emulator or Android
>   Mobile ?

If you are on `Emulator`, **Ensure you create an Google API based emulator**. *This emulator can also be used to test Google map and other Google Play Service integration.*

> 1) Its Ok if you use FragmentManager instead of SupportFragmentManager
>   and import the same !

2)Try declaring `static final LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33,151);` **before onCreate method**

```
3)Instead of Extending FragmentActivity you can extend Activity
```

Your code looks good!
But you can recheck these steps regarding API key:

4)Make sure you have properly created your API key in GoogleAPI console and also ACTIVATED the Google Maps Android API.**(Google console -> Services -> ON them)**

Use **Try-Catch** it will help you to trace your errors

```
try { 
       if (googleMap == null)
       {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
            findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
       }
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        Marker syd = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
        position(sydney).title("Its Sydney"));
    } catch (Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried the proposed amendments. Unfortunately the problem continued. At the beginning I had the message: Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk! But even after it was set, the app has continued to stop

Comment: I think then the issue is that system is unable to find         class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"   so try doing this : go to Project -> properties -> android and see that your project is including the Android maps.jar in your project  then go to Project -> properties ->  java build path -> libraries ->google apis and select one of the apis and following this steps make sure you mention it in manifest file as <application ...><uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />...</application>